# Is a sample of size $N$ uniquely described by $N$ sample moments?

Tags: statistics

I have the intuition that a sample of size $n$ should be able to be described uniquely by just N moments. But I don't know if that's true.

The idea is that, first, it is obvious that a sample of $n = 1$ can be uniquely describe by just the sample mean. For $n = 2$, knowing the first two (uncentered) moments is also enough because (if I did my maths correctly)

$$
X_1 = 2\overline{X} - X_2
$$
and

$$
M_2 = 1/2X_2^2 - 2M_1X_2+2M_1^2
$$
From which I can solve for $X_2$ and then $X_1$ by knowing $M_1$ and $M_2$.

It seems intuitive that this must hold on for $n > 2 $. The generalization for a sample of size $n$  and $m$ moments would be

\begin{matrix}
x_1 + x_2 + ... + x_n = nM_1\\ 
x_1^2 + x_2^2 +  ... + x_n^2 = nM_2 \\ 
       \vdots \\
 x_1^m + x_2^m + ... + x_n^m = nM_m
\end{matrix}

It these were linear equations, they would only have an unique solution for $n = m$ if the system described a full rank matrix. But they aren't, so... no dice.

From an information theory standpoint it seems to me (again, intuitively) that you shouldn't need more than $N$ numbers to represent any other $N$ numbers.

Note that I'm not trying to estimate the population distribution by the sample moments. I'm talking about describing a specific vector of $n$ values.

Also note that I assume that the order of samples does not matter so that $(x_1, x_2)$ and $(x_2, x_2)$ would be treated as the same solution.

Any hints on this problem?

Comment: It's not true that you can determine the values of each of $n$ variables with the first $n$ moments.  You can certainly determine the set of values in the sample but you can't know what, for instance, $x_1$ happens to be.  Consider a sample size of two with first and second raw moments 1/2 and 1.  There are two solutions:  $\left(x_1\to \frac{1}{2} \left(1-\sqrt{3}\right),x_2\to \frac{1}{2} \left(\sqrt{3}+1\right)\right)$ is one solution and $\left(x_1\to \frac{1}{2} \left(\sqrt{3}+1\right),x_2\to \frac{1}{2} \left(1-\sqrt{3}\right)\right)$ is another.

Comment: Fair point. I was implicitly assuming that the order didn't matter. (Although I intuit that if we defined each $x_i$ as a tuple $(X^a_i; X^b_i)$, then we could have an analogous situation but with the combined moments; covariance and the like).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can think of x_1,x_2, ...x_n as being the roots of a polynomial p of degree n.
From the [Newton identities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_identities) we can compute from the given moments M_1, M_2, ...,M_n the [elementary symmetric polynomials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_symmetric_polynomial)  in x_1,x_2,... x_n and hence the coefficients of the polynomial p. But the set of roots (without order) of p is determined by p. Hence, the values of x_1,x_2,...x_n are determined by M_1,M_2, ...,M_n except for a permutation of the values. This is the best that you can hope as the moments are invariant under such a permutation (as Elio example shows).

(Summing up a discussion with Elio via twiiter)